# How to pass model object to Web API Post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I want to save data to database in MVC application. I have below class which calls the webapi1 service post method. Here Sample is a model object. I have a view which uses the Sample object. I want to inert the Sample Object data to db using the service call.

```
public SampleTestCreate(Sample)
{
    string uri = baseUri + "Test";
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Test)));
      //  Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, Test);
        var data = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Test>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).Result;
     }
}

// POST api/Sample
public HttpResponseMessage PostSample(Sample Sample)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Samples.Add(Sample);
        db.SaveChanges();

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Sample);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = Sample.SampleID }));
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Here my service post method is getting called , but the "Sample" objects all the properties values are coming null. The model object binding is not happening.

Comment: For start please do not name variable same as Object type name. Example:
public HttpResponseMessage PostSample(Sample SampleObject)

Comment: Try instead of new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Test)) send new JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Test)

Comment: is it same as httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<Sample>(uri, sample);

Comment: So you've tried var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, Test)? And Test is an actual instance of Sample that you've set properties on?

Comment: yes,  But i got an error " Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required. Consider attributing the declaring type with [DataContract] and the property with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)].  " as well